# UIDocumentPickerViewController with UIDocumentPickerModeOpen mode not giving permission to edit the file in xcode (iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I want the user to select a file from files app and I've to read the contents of that file, modify it and write it in the same location.

I was trying to open the file using the following code:

```
UIDocumentPickerViewController *documentProvider;
documentProvider = [[UIDocumentPickerViewController alloc] initWithDocumentTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"public.comma-separated-values-text", nil] inMode: UIDocumentPickerModeOpen];
documentProvider.delegate = self;
documentProvider.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverFullScreen;
```

Delegate function:

`- (void)documentPicker:(UIDocumentPickerViewController *)controller didPickDocumentAtURL:(NSURL *)url
   {
       NSLog(@"%@", url.absoluteString);
   }`

But when I try to view or edit the file, it's showing error that I don't have view/write permission.

The URL that I received is file:///private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile%20Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/filename.csv

Is there any way to get permission for the files in iCloud? I found few third party apps which can modify the contents of the file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to access the file via a security scoped bookmark. Like such:

```
- (void) documentPicker: (UIDocumentPickerViewController *) controller
   didPickDocumentAtURL: (NSURL *) url
{
    if (controller.documentPickerMode == UIDocumentPickerModeOpen)
    {
            BOOL isAccess = [url startAccessingSecurityScopedResource];
            if(!isAccess)
            {
                return;
            }

            NSError * fileOpenError = nil;
            NSString * fileContents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL: url
                                                               encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                                  error: &fileOpenError];

            // FileContents should now be set properly.

            [url stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource];
    }
}
```

Comment: Been looking everywhere and the "startAccessingSecurityScopedResource" solved my own problem using UIDocumentBrowserViewController